Alfresco workflow - multi instance task with completion condition
I need help with my Activity workflow in Alfresco CE 7.4. I have approving user task with set multi instance. Task is very simple - users chooses from approve or reject. What I need is if one user choose reject, whole task and workflow ends. I tried to use completion condition to end user task and it works. But only for setting sequential=true (next user task via multi instance is not created).
If i set sequential=false (so all users tasks are created at start of task) it don't work.

I get PSQL error that gets ACS into infinite loop.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "act_ru_execution" violates foreign key constraint "act_fk_exe_parent" on table "act_ru_execution"
Detail: Key (id_)=(4575) is still referenced from table "act_ru_execution".

I found that problem is in terminate other users tasks, but for me is strange this ACS cant handle this. I work with alfresco for few years and never get PSQLException from application logic. I tried similar workaround throw signals and setting cancel activity = true and get same error.
Is this bug? And how to handle my case?
